# How to create bulk tasks in a Sharepoint List?

Tags: list

Is it possible to create Bulk Tasks for any SharePoint 2010 List?

There is no option to create multiple tasks in SharePoint. And, it is very cumbersome to create multiple task for the person who heads a project.

So can some one help me out on this?

-saumil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the tasks, there are ways to use SharePoint Foundation Remote Procedure Calls ([RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448359.aspx)) in combination with Collaborative Application Markup Language ([CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms426449.aspx)) to create batch operations on lists.

This includes deleting, updating, adding and other commands.

There is an article covering this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470842.aspx).

This can also be done from code. Examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx) and [here](http://snahta.blogspot.com/2008/11/batch-update-list-items-using-caml.html).

Answer (score 6):

Most efficient way of doing it in the UI I think is using the Datasheet view.

If you have an Excel spreadsheet with the columns laid out in the same way as the datasheet view, you can copy & paste from Excel directly into the Datasheet view.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, if you have a base set of tasks for each project, you could create them via workflow once a new project is added to your project list.